# User not created in postgres docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker image that's not accepting credentials for a user that is defined in the yaml docker-compose file. When I go to the docker console for the container and check users it only lists `postgres`. Not sure what I am missing - here's the yaml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    container_name: drewreport_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mpassword
      POSTGRES_USER: thedrewreport
      POSTGRES_DB: thedrewreportdb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - thedrewreportdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
  thedrewreportdata:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that `POSTGRES_USER` creates a user in Postgres, not in `/etc/passwd`. The way you test it is by connecting to postgres with the appropriate username and password (using, e.g. `psql` or an appropriate dirver in your language of choice). Your `docker-compose.yml` file works for me as written.

Comment: Yeah - there's no other users in the postgres database that are defined. I am not talking about user accounts. As I understand it this script is suppose to create a database user defined in this config?

Comment: More specifically when I type `\du` into the postgres console it only lists postgres

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. Running `docker-compose up`, I see:

```
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "docker_thedrewreportdata" with default driver
Creating docker_client_1 ...
Creating docker_db_1     ...
Creating docker_client_1 ... done
Creating docker_db_1     ... done
Attaching to docker_db_1, docker_client_1
[...]
db_1      | 2021-07-19 23:03:39.676 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

If I then connect with `psql`, I can authenticate using the username
and password you've defined in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# psql -h localhost -U thedrewreport  thedrewreportdb
Password for user thedrewreport:
psql (13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

thedrewreportdb=# \du
                                     List of roles
   Role name   |                         Attributes                         | Member of
---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 thedrewreport | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

thedrewreportdb=#
```

Note that any volumes specified in your `docker-compose.yml` will
persist between a `docker-compose down` and a `docker-compose up`, so
if you ever brought your stack up with different credentials, those
will never be replaced unless your explicitly destroy the volume by
running `docker-compose down -v`.

You can tell that `docker-compose` is re-using a volume if you don't
see a message like this when you run `docker-compose up`:

```
Creating volume "docker_thedrewreportdata" with default driver
```

Answer (score 0):

If existing, the existing DB data you mount to `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` will take precedence over the environment variables to initialize it.

You have 2 options:

- Update the existing DB data to add your user / password / database. To do so you can use `docker compose exec db bash` and then connect using `psql` command to make your changes.
- Delete or move your existing `thedrewreportdata` local volume, for instance updating it to `./thedrewreportdata_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/`

Once done, you can use `docker compose exec db psql --username thedrewreport --dbname thedrewreportdb` to doublecheck you can connect with your credentials to the updated DB.